# Function return input after it's done implementing (C++)

Tags: c++, function, fibonacci

I'm printng Fibonacci numbers calling the function in main():

```
cout << Fibonacci(HowMany, LastOne) << endl;
```

And the function itself is:

```c++
// function definition
unsigned long long Fibonacci(int InHowMany, char InLastOne)
{
    // assigning two initial numbers
    unsigned long long Num1 = 0, Num2 = 1; 

    // choosing the loop based on the user's choice of LastOne
    if(InLastOne == 'p')
    {   
        // printing the initial two values
        cout << "0" << endl;
        cout << "1" << endl;
        // iterating to print all the other values
        for (int i = 1; i < InHowMany; ++i)
        {
            unsigned long long Num2Temp = Num2;
            Num2 += Num1;
            Num1 = Num2Temp;
            // printing every value on the way with this instruction
            cout << Num2 << endl;
        }
    }
    // case when we just need to print the last number
    else if(InLastOne != 'p')
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < InHowMany; ++i)
        {
        unsigned long long Num2Temp = Num2;
        Num2 += Num1;
        Num1 = Num2Temp;
            // return condition
            if(i == InHowMany - 1)
            {
                return Num2;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

So it works, but somehow it always returns the HowMany \ InHowMany number at the very end of the program. And I know this probably (although, I am not sure) happens outside the loop, because I tried COUTing some random string and HowMany \ InHowMany appears after it...

Comment: Not all branches have a return value and thus this is undefined behaviour. Pay heed to your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Uhm, didn't get any mistakes from my compiler.

Comment: @Max if that's the case, you should probably do whatever it takes to crank up the warning level so you do. I sent this through clang and was immediately greeted with "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Comment: Yeah, it seems like -Wall should help me with that (advice from another thread). Should I delete the thread then? Sorry about that..